# Rails 4: passing parent's id for nested attributes when Updating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes

So, I'm trying to update a nested object, but for some reason the parent controller's `apps_params` aren't getting satisfied because the `app` isn't getting passed to it. Take a look below, and let me know if I should post any more code.

**Console error is as follows:**

```
Started PUT "/apps/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-03-21 14:00:12 -0500
Processing by AppsController#update as JSON
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"0Z/SxhhEO6OA6eiShd+1PZI0DQ9QK1I7G8wqoInz+vM=", "@app"=>{"element"=>{"@app"=>{"el
ent.name"=>"hgfd"}}}, "id"=>"1"}
  App Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "apps".* FROM "apps"  WHERE "apps"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
Completed 400 Bad Request in 2ms

ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: app):
  app/controllers/apps_controller.rb:73:in `app_params'
  app/controllers/apps_controller.rb:45:in `block in update'
  app/controllers/apps_controller.rb:44:in `update'
```

**The referenced lines in my `apps_controller.rb`:**

```
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @app.update(app_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @app, notice: 'App was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @app }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @app.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

private
def app_params
  params.require(:app).permit(:name, :infivewords, :description, elements_attributes: [:name, :description])
end
```

**My `Apps` Show `View`:**

```
<% @app.elements.each do |element| %>
  <tr>
        <td>    
              <span class="rest-in-place" data-url="<%= url_for @app %>" data-object="@app[element]" data-attribute="@app[element.name]" data-placeholder="Enter description">
                <%= element.name %>
        </td>
        <td><h2><%= element.description %></h2></td>
```

I've tried endlessly messing with the `View` to try to figure out why the heck the `app_id` isn't getting passed, but I'm at a loss, and can't seem to find the information I'm looking for anywhere.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

**EDIT:** I should add that in my routes, I have two separate resources blocks. One where elements is inside of apps, and another where features is inside elements. I'll post the code once I get back to my desk.

**EDIT2 - App Form View:**

```
<%= form_for(@app) do |f| %>
  <% if @app.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@app.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this app from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @app.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :infivewords %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :infivewords %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Can you add your app form? Params "@app" looks suspicious, maybe should be "app"?

Comment: @messanjah will do as soon as I get back to my desk in a few minutes, man. Thanks for the quick reply. Which "@app" are you referring to? Inside the view's do block? I've pretty much tried everything inside that do block and get either the same error, or no update and no error, but I'll try that again and post the console and browser's response.

Comment: The "@app" key in your Parameters hash. `app_params` requires ":app", but it looks like "@app" is being sent.

Comment: @messanjah I posted the App Form View in "EDIT2". You are indeed correct. I changed `@app` in the `do` block in the show view to just `app` and added `element` in the `permitted parameters` for `apps_params` in the `apps_controller`, and get a different console error: `Unpermitted parameters: element` even though I have whitelisted `element` in the `params`.

Comment: @messanjah, I'm referencing http://patshaughnessy.net/2014/6/16/a-rule-of-thumb-for-strong-parameters right now, but I'm not putting the pieces together as to how exactly I need to implement this. `Ctrl+F` for "It still doesn’t work. You get the same warning:" and you'll see it's talking about exactly what just happened to me, with rails not whitelisting the new `param`

Comment: Please add how App is related to Element.

Comment: @messanjah features is nested inside elements, and elements is nested within features, though has_many

Comment: @messanjah of course it's also embedded in the file system, controllers, and routes

Answer (score 1):

I'm unfamiliar with rest_in_place, but I would double-check your data attributes on this line

```
<span class="rest-in-place" data-url="<%= url_for @app %>" data-object="@app[element]" data-attribute="@app[element.name]" data-placeholder="Enter description">
```

Maybe something more like

```
<span class="rest-in-place" data-url="<%= url_for @app %>" data-object="app[elements]" data-attribute="name" data-placeholder="Enter description">
```

Comment: I agree, I've just updated my show view to reflect your suggestions. However, the console is throwing me the following error: `ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute: element):
  app/controllers/apps_controller.rb:45:in `block in update'
  app/controllers/apps_controller.rb:44:in `update'`

Comment: Maybe the plural form `app[elements]`?

Comment: I've tried that as well unfortunately, and it returns the following error: `ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch (Element(#39712560) expected, got Array(#3437496)): app/controllers/apps_controller.rb:45:in block in update' app/controllers/apps_controller.rb:44:in update'`